# SQL Trigger to run .Net aplication, can you do this?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I know nothing about MS SQL Server but need to know if it's possible to set some kind of trigger that whenever a criteria is met it will call a C# .exe and pass it a field for the database?

So whenever a new row is added it causes a C# app to run and passes it a value from the row...

Hope that makes sense to someone!

If so how do you add it? I think it's SQL 2003.

Comment: 2 questions; 1- do you want the C# to block the transaction from committing until the application completes? 2- where will the c# application run (same machine, different machine)?

Comment: SQL 2003 doesnt exist. So likely you must be on SQL 2000 / 2005. If on 2000, you can use extended stored procedures. On 2005, you have CLR integration. Like Dave has mentioned below, this sounds like a bad idea. Give more context as to why you want to do something like this. There might be a better option.

Comment: Hi 1 No I don't want it to block.
2. on the same server.

Comment: @InSane Thanks I was told it was 2003 (shows what I know about SQl!
I have added more info below Dave's comment. Thank you

Comment: I don't mean to change the context of your question, but what do you intend on doing in this C# executable that you "cannot" do leveraging SQL Server triggers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you thought of looking into a ssis package? This provides simple interaction between sql and c#.

Comment: If you get suplemental data from a web service you could build that into your ssis package. I would recommend spending a little time reading up on ssis. It's great for combining multiple processes, and pretty simple to use. I wanted to make sure you could use web service with it and alas you can http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/webservicessis.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use CLR Triggers http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131093(SQL.100).aspx

Comment: Thanks I will look into this if its a 2005 DB i was told its a 2003 but form  InSane comment above it can't be!

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can do this.  First, you can use a [CLR trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179562.aspx).

Second, you could use [xp_cmdshell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175046.aspx) to shell out to another app to get a value.

**Both are what I would consider to be very, very bad ideas**, especially if your knowledge of SQL Server is limited.  I would strongly, strongly consider not performing operations like the ones you're attempting inside of a trigger.  There are serious performance and security considerations to take into account either way you do it.

Instead of attempting to do what you're doing, I would suggest changing your application's code to perform updates like this there.

Comment: Limited No, non existent!

I guess I could poll the DB looking for new Updates but thought a trigger (if that's the right term) would be more efficient!?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a bad idea — there is a probably a better way to implement what you are trying to do. Can you provide more details around the business need?

Comment: OK Sorry for not giving enough info.
data is being pushed into the db from and external feed, however it doesn't have all the data need all the time. So I want to call a Web Service which has the supplemental data and append it to another table.

I know how to call the WEB Service etc but no idea about building some kind of trigger to call my application.

Thanks for all the help from you all thus far...

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just write a sql trigger to write to a table. Then poll with c# that table and look for a flag code and use that to invoke the c# message.

Comment: I did think of this but didn't want to keep hitting the DB when there may be not up date for x hours but when there is an update I need to quickly get the extra data.
Thanks for the suggestion anyway.